# HDMI input on Monitor only works with some devices

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, lenovo-laptop, external-display

I have an Acer 27" monitor with HDMI/D-Sub/DVI inputs. It works well with my camera, Macbook (using a DisplayPort to HDMI adaptor), Playstation3, Chromecast, Apple TV etc.

I recently got a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 260 and try as I might I can't get the Monitor to detect it. I have tried various combinations of HDMI cable and monitor and find that the Yoga is happy to output HDMI to my TV and my two Samsung monitors.

Has there been a change in the HDMI spec that might explain this? Or anything else? I am baffled. And angry as the warranty expired on the monitor a few months ago. Not that there's anything wrong with it - the issue only arises with this one laptop.

Comment: "Has there been a change in the HDMI spec" - Several what revision of HDMI does your Thinkpad support?  What revision of HDMI does your monitor support?  What revision does the HDMI cable support?  You should be updating your question to include the answers to these questions.

Comment: Check the list of supported formats and resolutions for each device and try forcing a common mode on each.